# tkinter: Controlling how OptionMenu shows long selections

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have an OptionMenu to choose from a list of what *can* be very long strings.  I don't want the window resizing all the time, so I've fixed the OptionMenu width to something can fully contain most of the options.

The problem I'm having is that when a very long option is selected, it is *centered* in the button, and also the lever bar thing (whatever that is) gets drawn on top of the last few letters (which just looks messy).  I would rather have it left-aligned, as the best chance of making sense of the string that won't fit would be to start reading it from the start, not somewhere randomly in the middle.

Is there any way to override how this is drawn?  There aren't really any options for OptionMenu.  Ideally, I'd like to truncate longer strings and append elipses (...) to indicate it doesn't fit, but at least getting it to left-align would be a big improvement.

It looks like it's built on top of a button of some sort; is there a way to get to that button so I can configure it?

Here's a working example if anyone wants to see exactly how OptionMenu handles long selections (python 2.6)...

```
root = Tk()

body = Frame(root)
body.pack()

chosen = StringVar( root)
om = OptionMenu( body, chosen, 'short option', 'this is anything but a short option, and wordy to boot!')
om.config( width=10)
om.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide the code,it would be a big help
Anyways,if you have used grid to align the **OptionMenu** then you can use a different column or increase the columnspan or can even use `sticky` to align it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sizing or placing the widget, it's completely about how the selected item is drawn on the button.  Posted code you can run to see what it does.

Comment: you can use `wraplength` in `om.config` then. It would show the whole text but in multiple lines.